# Is there a difference in appearance between semi and unsweetened chocolate?

Tags: chocolate

I bought semi and unsweetened baking chocolate in bulk but forgot to mark which was which....is there a way to figure out which one is which?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple visual difference.  A small taste will reveal all though--unsweetened chocolate is quite bitter.